# Decimal places formating in java based on variable from user

Tags: java

In java: I have some number and a number of desired decimal places in a variable (e.g. choosen by user),
and I need to print it.

```
myNumber = 3.987654;
numberOfDecimalPlaces = 4;
```

I dont want to do it like

```
System.out.printf( "%.4f", myNumber);
```

but I need to use VARIABLE `numberOfDecimalPlaces` instead.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the format string using `numberOfDecimalPlaces`:

```
System.out.printf( "%." + numberOfDecimalPlaces + 'f', myNumber);
```

Comment: @VivekSingh That's what he wanted to do. He said he doesn't want it to use a static number but wants it dynamically changing. This applies perfectly. +1

Comment: I go for this aswell even if I posted NumberFormat example

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand why @wero is not a good answer but if you don't like to use System.out.  maybe this..

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(numberOfDecimalPlaces);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(numberOfDecimalPlaces);
String toPrint = nf.format(myNumber);
```

Answer (score -1):

> You can try with this method :

```
//value is your input number and places for required decimal places

public static double function(double value, int places) {

    if (places < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
    value = value * factor;
    long tmp = Math.round(value);
    return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```